# Conditional statement in Objective C with two comparison operators in a single clause

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean

I've been learning Objective C lately, and I came across some code for using the accelerometer in an iPhone app. It works perfectly; however, there's one if-statement in the code which I simply cannot understand (both the meaning and why it works). The specific chunk is this:

```
if (0.2f < deviceTilt.y > -0.2f){position.x = 0;}
```

I just can't figure out the condition, and I hadn't seen the use of two comparison operators in one single clause before.

Hope somebody can help me out!

PS: The whole project can be found in this link: http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=151394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly atypical and most people wouldn't like it. To really understand what is going on, you have to understand C's operator precedence. See: http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html.

Let's analyze the statement knowing that conditionals associate left-to-right:

1) 0.2f < deviceTilt.y. This is either true (which is 1) or false (which is 0)

2) The result of (1) > -0.2f. Which should always be true.

So this is the same as if(1) or always true

Comment: Thank you very much! I deleted the unnecessary bit so it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

This is evaluated like:

let `y := .1`

```
if ((.2 < y) > -.2)

if (false > -.2)
```

false is treated as an int

```
if (0 > -.2)

if (true)
```

---

let `y := .3`

```
if ((.2 < y) > -.2)

if (true > -.2)
```

true is treated as an int

```
if (1 > -.2)

if (true)
```

-> always true

---

most likely this was meant:

```
if ((.2 < y) && (y > -.2))
```

Comment: Yes, I think they meant that too... now that I know what it means I won't use that kind of 'shortcut' because it might be confusing when reading code. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I didn't knew this but I definitely like it, and I'm going to use it more often. It's more like we're used to do in mathematics for defining bounds of a variable.